# Avoid React "no-unused-vars" error with loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, eslint

I am generating an array of objects based on the quantity of items in another array. Pretty simple, I'm just doing the following, which works fine.

```
for(let i in myArray){
  newArray.push({
    var1: someFunctionValue(),
    var2: anotherFunctionValue()
  });
}
```

However, because "i" is not being used, React (ESLint?) gives me the warning 'i' is assigned a value but never used - no-unused-vars.

Is there a better way I should be doing this? I don't really see a way to achieve what I want without producing this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a for-in loop over an array, without using the enumerable keys (indices). You should use `Array#forEach` instead, and since it accepts a callback, you can just omit any arguments:

```
myArray.forEach(() => { // No callback args
  newArray.push({
    var1: someFunctionValue(),
    var2: anotherFunctionValue()
  });
});
```

Also, now that I'm reading your variable names, it seems you're trying to do a mapping operation, as in for every element in `myArray`, you want a new one in `newArray` associated with each index. If that's the case, the better method is to `Array#map` your `myArray`:

```
const newArray = myArray.map(() => ({
  var1: someFunctionValue(),
  var2: anotherFunctionValue(),
}));
```

There's no need for any intermediacy and it's concise.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `myArray.forEach` doesn't work so well if you need to `await` something in the block. Also. I came to this question because I AM using the `i` variable. It might be a bug: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/12117

Comment: @ZachSmith That wasn't in the scope of the original question. You're free to edit the question title.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead which doesn't need a variable:

```
myArray.forEach(() => {
  newArray.push({
    var1: someFunctionValue(),
    var2: anotherFunctionValue()
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57870375/5405197). You can also try declaring the variable outside the loop.

For my use case I needed a `break` statement so `forEach()` wouldn't work for me.

```js
let i = null;
for(i in myArray){
  if (i==='fooBar') {
     break;
   } 
    else {
        newArray.push({
        var1: someFunctionValue(i),
        var2: anotherFunctionValue()
  });

}


}
```