# Why am I getting a 'no-unused-vars' warning in a for...of loop and how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint

I'm working on a React app created with Create React App. In every for...of loop, I get this weird 'no-unused-vars' warning pointing to the variable I have instantiated in the for statement.

**ESLint tells me my variable is not used, but it is actually used.**

Does anybody else get a similar warning? Is it an ESLint bug or am I doing something wrong here?
This is not a big issue, but it is annoying.
Thanks for your help.

```
   for (let track of tracks) {
        let chords = RavelFormatter.splitEntries(track.pitches)
        for (let chord of chords) {
            var n = chord.split(':')
            total += n.length
        }
    }
```

**Console output**

```
  Line 13:  'track' is defined but never used       no-unused-vars
  Line 15:  'chord' is defined but never used       no-unused-vars
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [avoid-react-no-unused-vars-error-with-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468477/avoid-react-no-unused-vars-error-with-loop)

Comment: @tarunkhosla Doesn't look like it - here, the variables *are* being used

Comment: As an aside, try to make more use of `const` in your code - it makes your intent easier to understand at a glance, and reduces cognitive overhead in having to keep track of variables that may potentially be reassigned.

Comment: @CertainPerformance , yes you are correct. However the question [avoid-react-no-unused-vars-error-with-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468477/avoid-react-no-unused-vars-error-with-loop) answer the above question in comment section of upvoted answer. it says take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/12117)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @SamHH, thanks for the advice. I'm actually converting some old code to ES6 and get rid of all `var` declarations.

Comment: @BenjaminMartinez Same goes for the `let` in your loops, they're not being reassigned so they can/should be `const`.

Answer (score 13):

Please upgrade the `babel-eslint` package to version `10.0.3`.

This will most likely fix those false-positives where vars are used inside loops and wrongly reported as unused.

Comment: If you are using create-react-app, you want to upgrade react-scripts to 3.1.2 or newer. `yarn add --exact react-scripts@3.1.2`

Comment: I had to upgrade to `babel-eslint` version 10.1.0 for this to go away.

Comment: `babel-eslint` is now deprecated and will not receive further updates. Please, use `@babel/eslint-parser` instead. **Don't forget** to set it as your `parser` in `parserOptions` !

Comment: Upgrading react-scripts from 3.1.1 -> 3.1.2 does work. However at some point later it seems the error was re-introduced and is again present in react-scripts as at 5.0.0

Answer (score 11):

See [issue 12117](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/12117), which is related to a specific version of ESLint. You can revert your ESLint version back to v6.1.0 to resolve this.

Comment: I upgraded to `eslint` 6.8.0 and `babel-eslint` 10.1.0 to fix this issue. Much better than reverting.

Comment: `babel-eslint` is now deprecated and will not receive further updates. Please, use `@babel/eslint-parser` instead. Don't forget to set it as your `parser` in `parserOptions` !

Answer (score 10):

### Upgrade to `eslint` 6.8.0 and `babel-eslint` 10.1.0.

This is a known issue with `babel-eslint` and is related to the `eslint-scope` version used. It looks like it started in `eslint` 6.1.0.

Just upgrade your packages to (at least):

```
"babel-eslint": 10.1.0,
"eslint": 6.8.0
```

You can view the Github Issues here:

- https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/12117
- https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/issues/791

Comment: eslint 7.12.1 with babel-eslint 10.1.0 and I am still seeing this issue

Comment: @wogsland You should post that on the Github issues for `eslint` and `babel-eslint` to get their input because this issues has been fixed and you may be running into something else.

Comment: `babel-eslint` is now deprecated and will not receive further updates. Please, use `@babel/eslint-parser` instead

Comment: **Don't forget** to set it as your `parser` in `parserOptions` !

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix it by using this.

```
let track = null;

for (track of tracks) {
    let chords = RavelFormatter.splitEntries(track.pitches)
    for (let chord of chords) {
        var n = chord.split(':')
        total += n.length
    }
}
```

Comment: clever, give you that @martin